# How to make the new elasticsearch node.js client only returns body in promises?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

"The returned value of an API call will no longer be the body, statusCode, and headers for callbacks, and only the body for promises. The new returned value will be a unique object containing the body, statusCode, headers, warnings, and meta, for both callback and promises."

This is a problem if I stringify and store the result in redis (now I will need to JSON parse when I get the value back from redis). Is there anyway I can switch on "body only" mode on promises?

Comment: Can you add your code? I'm not sure what the problem is here - couldn't you just e.g. deconstruct the body from the response like `const { body} = await client.search(...)`?

Comment: @eol I could but I also have written 384 queries for different purposes some of them have integrated cache. Changing all of them and test them all will take at least two to three hours.

Comment: I see that would be a lot of work :/ Check my answer - maybe it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could overwrite/proxy the `search()` method of your `Client`-instance. So you could define your proxy with something like:

```
function initializeSearchProxy(client) {
    const origSearch = client.search;
    client.search = async function () {
        const {body} = await origSearch.apply(this, arguments);
        return body;
    }
}
```

Then initialize your search-proxy after requiring and instantiating the elasticsearch-`Client`,

```
const {Client} = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new Client({node: 'http://localhost:9200'});
initializeSearchProxy(client);
...
// all client.search calls now return the body directly
```

Comment: I am using this method. I was just wondering if there is a setting I can turn on to enable this feature.

Comment: Afaik there's no such option unfortunately.

Comment: BTW it's not .call, it's .apply

Comment: You're right - or you do `.call(this, ...arguments)` :) I'll fix it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unforntunately, no.
There is no way to only receive only the body.
As you mentioned this would be the response,

```
{
  body: object | boolean
  statusCode: number
  headers: object
  warnings: [string]
  meta: object
}
```

Best you can do it before you store the response in Redis you can store it like this,

```
const {body} = await client.search({
  index: 'my-index',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
})
// Now you can store the body in Redis
```

Or when you fetch the response object from Redis you can do this,

```
const {body}=JSON.parse(fetchFromRedis(id));
```

Comment: I have written 384 queries for different purposes some of them have integrated cache. Changing all of them and test them all will take at least two to three hours.

Comment: Also when you fetch from redis you get a string instead of an object...

Comment: Your only options are the ones above. If not you can either look for alternative clients or write your own